# What does the repetition of 好きで好きで mean instead of just 好き?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 好きで好きでどうしようもないぐらい好きだった
> I loved her so much that I didn't know what to do with myself

Why 好きで is used twice? Is it for emphasis? And what does もないぐらい mean?

Comment: There is no lexical term もないぐらい.  The important phrase is どうしようもない.  A slightly different formulation of しようがない, which you've probably heard.  ぐらい is a variation of くらい.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that すき is a na-adjective technically. So it is a repetition of adjective, which can happen in English as well (e.g. the Beatles has [Blue Blue Sky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHrl8x2fHyI)).

Hopefully the following help to see a general pattern.

- 若いころは旅行が楽しくて楽しくて世界中回った
- In youth, I liked travelling so much and traveled all around the world.
- 働くのが嫌で嫌でいつもさぼっている
- I hate and hate working, so am always slacking.
- かゆくてかゆくてたまらない
- It is so itchy and I can't bear it.

Note that the repeating part is usually some sort of feeling/sensation.

(I don't know if *hate and hate* works, but you know what I mean...)

---

Re どうしようもないくらい, it is easier just to remember [どうしようもない](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%A6%82%E4%BD%95%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%82%82%E7%84%A1%E3%81%84/#jn-154928) is one word meaning *there is nothing that can be done/no way/hopeless*. くらい is *(to the) extent/degree*.

Overall, the sentence means *I loved her so much. So much so that there was nothing that could be done about it*.